# How did the silent 't' come into all these 'tch' words?

Tags: orthography, silent-letters, consonants

I'm curious as to how so many words with the 'ch' sound have the silent 't' in them. *Catch, itch, retch, hatchet, botch* etc. The list is huge.

They all have different origins, and yet they have the silent 't'. But words like *achieve, lecherous, spinach* don't have the silent 't'.

Can anyone see any phonological patterns that might have led to this?

Comment: In some of your examples, I don't think the T is entirely silent.

Comment: Perhaps there's a geographical consideration here -- in Western Canada me and my friends pronounce the "tch" more sharply than "ch" (without the "t").

Comment: onomatomaniak@: The consonant represented by ‘tch’ in all the OP’s examples is, at least, in BrEng, /tʃ/. That’s the sound found at the beginning and end of ‘church’.

Comment: To my ears, the final consonant sounds in *spinach* and *itch* are different (if only slightly).

Comment: It seems to me that the 'tch' behaves in English spelling the way a doubled consonant would, and the 'ch' the way a single consonant would. That is, 'tch' is more likely to occur after short vowels. For example, you'd never put two 't's after an 'r'. So 'hurt' and 'church', 'better' and 'catcher', 'peach' and 'seat'.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: The final consonant of ‘spinach’ is indeed different. It’s /dʒ/, the same as that found at the beginning and end of ‘judge’.

Comment: @Barrie: American dictionaries have /tʃ/ for *spinach;* however, it seems to me that it's pronounced both /tʃ/ and /dʒ/ in the U.S., just like *sandwich* and *ostrich.* This may be an instance of a systematic change in /-ɪtʃ/ in an unstressed syllable.

Comment: If there's a change going on there, it hasn't reached my part of the US yet.... I hear and say no difference in any of the "ch" sounds given so far.  "Spinach" does not match "judge" at all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, the T is not entirely silent. The words that do include the T has a kind of a T-sound starting it off. If you look at another word where the ch is not including the T is "bachelor", and it is not so sharp (more like a D-sound than a T-sound). The difference is very small, but it is there.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary disagrees. See my comment above.

Comment: Can you distinguish the final sounds in 'rich' and 'ditch'? 'much' and 'dutch'?

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that the 'tch' behaves in English spelling the way a doubled consonant would, and the 'ch' the way a single consonant would. That is, 'tch' is more likely to occur after short vowels, so you see *patch, botch,* and *crutch,* but *beach, roach,* and *pooch*. As with any English spelling rule, there are numerous exceptions.

Comment: Shor, good point. Exceptions are there, as you said. Such, much, spinach, lecherous...

Comment: @Alain: It looks to me like the *a* in *spinach* used to be long. OED says that among other spellings, it was spelled *spinnage* or *spinache* in Middle English. I can't explain the others.

Answer (score 5):

The words you mention have been spelt in many different ways over the centuries. To take just two examples, *hatchet* has also appeared as *hachet, acchett, hachit, hachytt, hachette and hatchette* and *achieve* as *acheui acheeve, achyeue, atcheue, acheue, acheve, achieue, achyue, achieve, achiue, ascheve, atcheive, atchive, atchieue, atchiue, atchive, atchieve, acheive, atcheeue; acheive, acheue, atcheve, achieve and acheive.* Make of that what you will.

Comment: Some of those ‘achieve’ spellings look far more like an attempt to write the act of sneezing onomatopoeically.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet U and V used to be the same letter, and weren't consistently distinguished until after the printing press took over, and even then the "consistent distinction" wasn't the modern one (based on sound, rather than position) until much, much later

Comment: @NoName I’m aware of that. I can’t say for certain what I had in mind when I wrote my comment nearly ten years ago, but I presume it was a joke, based on how the variant forms (particularly in such extreme repetition) looks to a modern reader.

Comment: Fair, should have known you would know. This is EL&U, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I side with onomatomaniak — I pronounce *botch* differently to *leech*.

I think looking at the etymologies of the words shows where the *t* comes from:

- Batch [from O.E. *bæcce](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=batch)
- Hatch ["opening," O.E. hæc (gen. hæcce)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hatch)
- Itch [from O.E. gicce](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=itch)
- Thatch [from O.E. þeccan](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=thatch)

Compared to

- Church [from O.E. cirice](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=church)
- -arch [from Gk. arkh-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=arch-)
- Finch [from O.E. finc, from P.Gmc. *finkiz](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=finch)
- Leech [from O.E. læce](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=leech)

(All of the above are taken from [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com))

I think there is a pattern that words that originally have *cc* become *tch*, whereas words with a single *c* or *k* become ch. Obviously there will be exception, but I think that this is where the majority come from.

Comment: Botch and church are not a good set of examples to give, mostly because church has the r in between. Botch and leech, maybe. I think there is a a slight, momentary 'hold and release' action of the tongue with the tch words; with non 't' ch sounds, it's a smoother pronunciation.

Comment: @Akin: fair point. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Akin: indeed, to really compare them meaningfully, you have to give examples where the vowel is the same, eg *rich* and *ditch*, or *much* and *Dutch*, as \@Mitch suggests above.  If you don’t mind invoking a proper noun, there’s an actual putative minimal pair in *rich* and the name *Ritch*.  Would you really pronounce any of these differently, or be able to tell the difference in someone else’s pronunciation?  I don’t think I would.

Comment: I would think "which" and "witch" would be better examples.  Consider the question "Just so I'm clear, Witch Number One visited Witch Number Two?"  I would posit that someone reading that sentence would pronounce it noticeably differently from "Just so I'm clear, which number one visited which number two?"  Even if the differences between "which" and "witch" would normally be slight, I would expect a speaker to exaggerate them in cases where obvious ambiguity would otherwise exist.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because the 'ch' sound used to be pronounced as in the Scottish 'loch', so the 't' is added to indicate the harder sound?

Comment: Hi, Hilary. Welcome to English Language and Usage. This community is not a discussion forum and we encourage an answer with research/reference/link that can support it. Please make sure you visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. You can post a comment when you have 50 reputation points.

Comment: @Rathony Hilary is new and cannot comment yet I s'pose -- so it's posted as an "answer." I think there's a useful hypothesis there, though: "the 't' is added to indicate the harder sound?"

Comment: @Kris Yes. That's why I commented "You can post a comment when you have 50 reputation points." I am not sure about the useful hypothesis, but it needs addttional explanation to stand as an answer.